# How to write a subset of $\mathbb{C}^4$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, invariant-subspace

I'm currently working with the standard representation of the symmetric group $S_n$. Recall that the standard representation of $S_n$ permutes the basis elements of the $n \times n$ identity matrix and applies it to an element $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

I have noted that in $\mathbb{C}^4$, the subspace defined by $K=$ Span$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is $S_4$-invariant. We note that

$$K^\bot = Span \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0  
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix} \end{Bmatrix}$$

Now, normally we would write $\pi(12)$ and $\pi(1234)$ as permutations of $4 \times 4$ matrices, but when we restrict $\pi$ to $K^\bot$, I want to treat $K^\bot$  as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$ instead of $\mathbb{C}^4$ and therefore I will need new mappings to generate all of the mappings of $\pi$. How can I do this?

---

**NOTE:** The entire reason that I need to do this is because I am seeking to prove that $\pi \big|_{K^\bot}$ is irreducible. Unfortunately, with $K^\bot$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^4$, I obtain $\langle \chi_\pi, \chi_\pi \rangle > 1$, which is clearly an issue. But I'm thinking that if I can view this instead in $3$-space, I'll resolve my issue. I just don't know how to do so.

Comment: The usual approach to find $\chi_{K^\bot}$ is to note that $\chi_K = 1$ as $S_n$ acts trivially on $K$. So $\chi_{K^\bot} = \chi_\pi - 1$. But you can calculate these traces explicitly - for each conjugacy class of $S_n$, take your favourite representative element (in this case, ideally one that fixes $1$), work out the matrix of the linear map it induces with respect to the basis you gave for $K^\bot$, and take its trace.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I can't make a matrix using $K^\bot$ as a basis because $\dim(K^\bot) < \dim(\mathbb{C}^4)$

Comment: Are you happy about these facts

*(a): Each $\sigma \in S_4$ gives you a well-defined linear map from $K^\bot$ to $K^\bot$ (by restricting the linear map it induces on $\Bbb C^4$).

(b): We have a finite basis $\mathcal B$ for $K^\bot$.

(c): For any linear map $K^\bot \to K^\bot$, we can write down its matrix with respect to the basis $\mathcal B$.*

?
In particular (c) is purely a linear algebra fact. If you are happy with all of these, then you can combine them together to find matrices for elements of $S_4$ acting on $K^\bot$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear algebra teaches us to write linear operators with respect to bases as matrices.

Your basis for $K^\perp$ is

$$ a=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad
b = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
c = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}. $$

Check how $(12)$ transforms these:

$$ (12)a=-a $$
$$ (12)b = b-a $$
$$ (12) c=c-a $$

which tells us $(12)=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$